# Sourcepath not found

Tags: java, eclipse

When using Eclipse's debug feature, I get "Sourcepath not found" for String.replace(). It was working perfectly fine last night and I haven't changed anything other than the code it's self.

```
msg = msg.replace("[bold]",config.tags[1]);
```

is what's triggering it by the looks of it.

Comment: Let's see the code then.

Comment: I do not like crystal balls, whether they work or not.

Comment: You must have a JDK in you class path not just a JRE because JDK is the one that contains the src.zip.

Comment: Sorry, the whole message didn't go through the first time for some reason.

Comment: By the by, I get this some times when I'm not looking at what I'm doing. If you're using maven, its popular to have wrapper projects that includes the rest of your projects as modules (makes it easier to build). When I do a global search and don't pay attention to the results, I end up trying to modify something on my wrapper project instead of the real maven artifacts holding the source. Eclipse tells me that exact same thing when that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your Java VM settings in your preferences are what you expect and they are pointed to a JDK that has the source available. Maybe something in your Java environment changed.

Comment: where would I find this? I can't see Java VM in preferences (I'm a noob with eclipse at the minute)

Comment: Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: Looks like you are pointed to a JRE definition. You want the JRK which has the src.zip file in it's root folder.

Comment: OK, now you should be able to debug it though and find out why you are getting the NPE, run it with the debugger and set a Java Exception breakpoint on NullPointerException.

Comment: It's probable that the 2nd argument to .replace is null.

Comment: Hi, replacing the second argument has fixed it. I'll look for a way around it (due to tags[1] being the bold character for IRC)